# CSS blur and overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Update**

I have created a simliar jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ckaeno9s/
In safari this works correctly. In chrome it does not. If you remove overflow:hidden; from line 15 you'll notice that the blur is now being applied in the correct way.

This jsfiddle sums up the problem well.

**Original Message**

I am trying to create a blurred banner effect and it is working pretty well in Safari (bottom) but not so well in Chrome (top).

[image: example]

How this is working is that something too big is being placed into a div in the header with a blur effect applied via -webkit-filter in the CSS, then the header has an overflow: hidden applied to it. I think what is happening is the overflow: hidden is being applied before the blur in chrome, so then a smaller image is left to blur, giving the soft edges. Whereas in Safari, the filter is being applied before the overflow: hidden. If I increase the size of my div with overlow hidden I get the following:

[image]

which is correct at the bottom of the header but obviously now it is flowing out of my header. Is there any way I can get my overflow: hidden to be applied after the blur? Or just achieve the same effect in chrome as I'm getting in safari.

```
.content-blurred {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter:url(#blur-effect);
    opacity:1;
    z-index: 1;
}

#header {
    overflow:hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height:38px;
}
```

**To summarise my question**: I want to create hard edges on a blurred div.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tbsksa18/1/

### html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="miss-blurry"></div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.parent{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.miss-blurry{
    width: 130%;
    height: 130%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://www.freeallimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/dog-1.jpg) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
    transform: translate(-15%, -15%);
}
```

Comment: Updated for better results by using translate transform instead of left/top.

Comment: This is correct and when I can get this to work as a banner correctly. However, I can't get it to work with my javascript (see jsfiddle in question).